# Periodical interruptions Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I sumarize my problem through this piece of code. When I end my program by closing the tkinter main window, I need the whole program ends, but the loops goes on executing until the functions is over. I suppose there is a way to force these functions ends too. I think there is a way to detect the program was ended, so I could end the functions.

```
import threading

import time

from tkinter import *

def loop1_10():

    for i in range(1, 11):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)

def loop1_10_b():

    for i in range(1, 11):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)


threading.Thread(target=loop1_10).start()

threading.Thread(target=loop1_10_b).start()

MainWindow = Tk()

MainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way to handle this is to make the threads "daemons".  A daemon thread will be forcibly closed when the app exits; it doesn't block the app.

```
threading.Thread(target=loop1_10, daemon=True).start()
threading.Thread(target=loop1_10_b, daemon=True).start()
```

Note that I'm not saying one is better or worse than the other.  Each option has its uses.

Comment: Thank you Tim. You are right. This is the way.

Comment: `Proceso1 = threading.Thread(target=loop1_10) 
Proceso1.setDaemon(True) 
Proceso1.start() 

Proceso2 = threading.Thread(target=loop1_10_b) 
Proceso2.setDaemon(True) 
Proceso2.start()`

Answer (score 0):

Add a protocol, `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`, to your `MainWindow`, where you use define a function you defined, `on_close()` that gets called once the tkinter window is closed.

The `on_close()` function will redefine the global variable `end` from `False` into `True`, and in each `for` loop, if the `end` variable's value is `True`, `return` out of them:

```
import threading
import time
from tkinter import *

def loop1_10():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        if end:
            return
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)

def loop1_10_b():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        if end:
            return
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)

end = False
def on_closing():
    global end
    end = True
    MainWindow.destroy()

threading.Thread(target=loop1_10).start()
threading.Thread(target=loop1_10_b).start()

MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
MainWindow.mainloop()
```

But there is still a problem with the above code; if the `end = True` happened right before the `time.sleep()` call(s), the last `time.sleep()`(s) will still make the program wait for a second or two before terminating.

To fix this, use `time.time()` and a `while` loop to manually check how much time has passed before continuing each `for` loop:

```
import threading
import time
from tkinter import *

def loop1_10():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        old_time = time.time()
        while True:
            if end:
                return
            if time.time() - old_time < 1:
                continue
            break
        print(i)

def loop1_10_b():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        old_time = time.time()
        while True:
            if end:
                return
            if time.time() - old_time < 2:
                continue
            break
        print(i)

end = False
def on_closing():
    global end
    end = True
    MainWindow.destroy()

threading.Thread(target=loop1_10).start()
threading.Thread(target=loop1_10_b).start()

MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
MainWindow.mainloop()
```

But do note from this comment by @kindall:

> `use time.time() and a while loop` -- don't do this, it'll use up an entire CPU core waiting for the loop to exit. this will not only eat battery unnecessarily, but since Python only uses one CPU core due to the Global Interpreter Lock, it will make the rest of the program sluggish, too

Comment: `use time.time() and a while loop ` -- don't do this, it'll use up an entire CPU core waiting for the loop to exit. this will not only eat battery unnecessarily, but since Python only uses one CPU core due to the Global Interpreter Lock, it will make the rest of the program sluggish, too.

Comment: @kindall I see. So it's the `time.time()` call that uses a lot of CPU?

Comment: @kindall Thank for your warning. Is the problem in time.time() instruction? Do this command use a lot of CPU core?

Comment: It's not any particular statement that uses a lot of CPU, it's the fact that you're executing code the whole time.